# MATLAB: Loop through the values of a list from 'who' function

Tags: matlab, list, variable-length-array

I have a long list of variables in my workspace. 
First, I'm finding the potential variables I could be interested in using the `who` function. Next, I'd like to loop through this list to find the size of each variable, however `who` outputs only the name of the variables as a string.

How could I use this list to refer to the values of the variables, rather than just the name?

Thank you,

```
list = who('*time*')
list = 

    'time'
    'time_1'
    'time_2'

for i = 1:size(list,1);
    len(i,1) = length(list(i))
end

len =

     1
     1
     1
```

Comment: This is exactly the reason why dynamic variable names are bad. You tie your hand and lead yourself down a rocky path that ends in `eval`. I suggest that you use a cell, or even better, a struct instead, for storing your data. So instead of `time`, `time_1`, `time_2` etc, have `timestruc.f1`, `timestruc.f2`, etc. You can access those fields dynamically, using `timestruc.('f1')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want details about the variables, you can use `whos` instead which will return a struct that contains (among other things) the dimensions (`size`) and storage size (`bytes`).

As far as getting the *value*, you *could* use `eval` **but this is not recommended and you should instead consider using cell arrays or structs with dynamic field names rather than dynamic variable names**.

```
S = whos('*time*');

for k = 1:numel(S)
    disp(S(k).name)
    disp(S(k).bytes)
    disp(S(k).size)

    % The number of elements
    len(k) = prod(S(k).size);

    % You CAN get the value this way (not recommended)
    value = eval(S(k).name);
end
```

Comment: thank you for your help. How may I use the `whos` list in a `for` loop to assign the fields of a `struct` which will contain the values of `time` as well, instead of name, bytes & size only?

Comment: That is a different question than what you have asked here. I suggest asking a new question and marking this as a solution if it answered your original question

Answer (score 7):

[@Suever nicely explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226345/5067311) the straightforward way to get this information. As I noted in a comment, I suggest that you take a step back, and don't generate those dynamically named variables to begin with.

You can access structs dynamically, without having to resort to the slow and unsafe `eval`:

```
timestruc.field = time;
timestruc.('field1') = time_1;
fname = 'field2';
timestruc.(fname) = time_2;
```

The above three assignments are all valid for a struct, and so you can address the fields of a single data struct by generating the field strings dynamically. The only constraint is that field names have to be valid variable names, so the first character of the field has to be a letter.

But here's a quick way out of the trap you got yourself into: save your workspace (well, the relevant part) in a .mat file, and read it back in. You can do this in a way that will give you a struct with fields that are exactly your variable names:

```
time = 1;
time_1 = 2;
time_2 = rand(4);
save('tmp.mat','time*'); % or just save('tmp.mat')
S = load('tmp.mat');
```

afterwards `S` will be a struct, each field will correspond to a variable you saved into `'tmp.mat'`:

```
>> S

S = 

      time: 1
    time_1: 2
    time_2: [4x4 double]
```

Comment: @ Andras, thank you for your help. Is there a way to assign the `struct` using the list found from `whos` instead of manually assigning each `field`? So, for every dataset, the variable names could be different, as well as the sampling rate. For the above example, I'd like to group these `time` variables & find out which other variables match the size of each of these times, or in the other words, group the channels with appropriate `time` based on the length of variables.

Comment: @BehnazEnsan I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want to transform your variables named `time_1`, `time_2` etc. to the fields of a new struct, that can only be done either using `eval` (which I'd advise against) or using `save`/`load`, as I explained in my answer. Then if you have a cell of field names as strings, `tcell = {'time_1','time_2'};` etc, you can loop over this cell, and dynamically access the given field of the struct: `for tstring in tcell, tmpvar = S.(tstring); <do stuff here>; end`. Or you can just loop over the fields of the struct, `fieldnames(S)`, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

An example writing variables from workspace to csv files:

```
clear;

% Writing variables of myfile.mat to csv files
load('myfile.mat');
allvars = who;
for i=1:length(allvars)
    varname = strjoin(allvars(i));
    evalstr = strcat('csvwrite(', char(39), varname, '.csv', char(39), ', ', varname, ')');
    eval(evalstr);
end
```