# Matlab: Defining a hardcoded matlab code dynamically? How can i do this in order of my code?

Tags: matlab

Is there the possibility to create my diagram options(i), diagramlimits(i) and inputdata(i) dynamically with a for loop - or with another way -> i=3? I don't want to write it hard coded like in my code at the moment.

At the moment a big part of my code is repeating. Only the variable names are changing. I will avoid this. I will replace it with variables based with an index??? 
**My Code:**

```
clear all 
clear clc 


diagramoptions = [];
diagramlimits = [];
inputdata = [];


diagramoptions2 = [];
diagramlimits2 = [];
inputdata2 = [];

diagramoptions3 = [];
diagramlimits3 = [];
inputdata3 = [];



wholecontent = fileread('Rainflow_Data_Limits_Settings.txt')
sections = regexp(wholecontent, '\*+([^*]+)\*+([^*]+)', 'tokens')

for section = sections
   switch(strtrim(section{1}{1}))

       case 'Diagram Options' %Diagram Options -> siehe meine Gliederung im .txt file
          keyvalues = regexp(section{1}{2}, '([^\n\r=]+)=([^\n\r=]+)', 'tokens')%\n -> new line; \r carriage return
          diagramoptions = cell2table(vertcat(keyvalues{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Key', 'Value'})

       case 'Diagram Limits'
          header = strsplit(regexp(section{1}{2}, '[^\n\r]*', 'match', 'once'))
          content = textscan(section{1}{2}, repmat('%f', 1, numel(header)), 'HeaderLines', 2)
          diagramlimits = table(content{:}, 'VariableNames', header)

       case 'Input Data'
          inputdata = cell2mat(textscan(section{1}{2}, '%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1))%dh: ich habe 1 Headerline zur besseren übersicht

       case 'Diagram Options2' %Diagram Options -> siehe meine Gliederung im .txt file
          keyvalues2 = regexp(section{1}{2}, '([^\n\r=]+)=([^\n\r=]+)', 'tokens')%\n -> new line; \r carriage return
          diagramoptions2 = cell2table(vertcat(keyvalues{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Key', 'Value'})


       case 'Diagram Limits2'
          header2 = strsplit(regexp(section{1}{2}, '[^\n\r]*', 'match', 'once'))
          content2 = textscan(section{1}{2}, repmat('%f', 1, numel(header2)), 'HeaderLines', 2)
          diagramlimits2 = table(content2{:}, 'VariableNames', header2)    

       case 'Input Data2'
          inputdata2 = cell2mat(textscan(section{1}{2}, '%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1))%dh: ich habe 1 Headerline zur besseren übersicht

        case 'Diagram Options3' %Diagram Options -> siehe meine Gliederung im .txt file
          keyvalues3 = regexp(section{1}{2}, '([^\n\r=]+)=([^\n\r=]+)', 'tokens')%\n -> new line; \r carriage return
          diagramoptions3 = cell2table(vertcat(keyvalues{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Key', 'Value'})

       case 'Diagram Limits3'
          header3 = strsplit(regexp(section{1}{2}, '[^\n\r]*', 'match', 'once'))
          content3 = textscan(section{1}{2}, repmat('%f', 1, numel(header3)), 'HeaderLines', 2)
          diagramlimits3 = table(content3{:}, 'VariableNames', header3)


       case 'Input Data3'
          inputdata3 = cell2mat(textscan(section{1}{2}, '%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1))%dh: ich habe 1 Headerline zur besseren übersicht

      otherwise
          warning('Unknown section: %s', section{1}{1})
   end
end

%öffnet die output fenster
openvar diagramoptions
openvar diagramlimits 
openvar inputdata 

openvar diagramoptions2
openvar diagramlimits2
openvar inputdata2 

openvar diagramoptions3
openvar diagramlimits3 
openvar inputdata3
```

**My Input:** (Rainflow_Data_Limits_Settings.txt - File)

```
******************* Diagram Options****************
number_of_plots=4
color=red
linewidth=12
header=Number of cycles
xlabel= RPM
ylabel= Amount
******************* Diagram Limits****************
xmin xmax ymin ymax zmin zmax
2   7   0   12  12  343
*******************Input Data****************
-220.8  228 50045
-222    201.6   50045
-224.4  196.8   200176
******************* Diagram Options2****************
number_of_plots=4
color=red
linewidth=12
header=Number of cycles
xlabel= RPM
******************* Diagram Limits2****************
xmin xmax ymin ymax zmin zmax
2   7   0   12  12  343
*******************Input Data2****************
-220.8  228 50045
-220.2  198 200176
-224.4  196.8   200176
******************* Diagram Options3****************
number_of_plots=4
color=red
linewidth=12
xlabel= RPM
ylabel= Amount
******************* Diagram Limits3****************
xmin xmax ymin ymax zmin zmax
2   7   0   12  12  343
*******************Input Data3****************
-220.8  228 50045
-222    201.6   50045
```

Comment: Please don't do this! Exactly for what you're seeing: it makes your life miserable, and also the life of anybody involved in your code. The presence of `eval` is a very good sign. Use cells, or even better, structs with dynamic field names. [Example of what I mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226214/matlab-loop-through-the-values-of-a-list-from-who-function/40226542#40226542) for a different problem.

Comment: @Andras Deak, i understood. I have deleted this test "code part". I am new in matlab. Can you give me an example regarding structs/cells. Sorry i have no idea how to do it. I have worked several hours for this code :/

Comment: Argh, sorry, I meant "*the presence of `eval` is a very good sign that you're doing something wrong*". What I would do is to switch from `var1`,`var2`,`var3` to either a cell with `var{1},var{2},var{3}` containing what you have now, or a struct with something like `var.f1,var.f2,var.f3` etc. But in the struct case, you can even drop the numbers, and use meaningful field names, if that makes sense. The huge difference between your original and the struct one is that in the latter case you can use `fname='f1'; var.(fname)=...` to dynamically (and safely) assign to a field of the struct.