# Multiple plots coombine and concatenate in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

The problem is that I have a for loop as follows:

```
for i=1:(rx * tx)    
    for j=1:(rx * tx)
        eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d_t = corrcoef(m_a%d_abs, m_b%d_abs)', pairs(i), pairs(j), pairs(i), pairs(j)));
        eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d = t_%d_%d_t(1, 2)', pairs(i), pairs(j), pairs(i), pairs(j)));

        if(eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d', pairs(i), pairs(j))) >= max_cor)
            eval(sprintf('figure(''name'', ''a (%d) <> b (%d)'')', pairs(i), pairs(j)));
            eval(sprintf('plot(a%d, ''r'')', pairs(i)));
            hold on;
            eval(sprintf('plot(b%d, ''b'')', pairs(j)));
            xlabel('Tones (f)');
        end
    end
end
```

this for loop plots each Plot in a new window according to the if statement like this plot [image]

I want to concatenate each next plot after the last plot so that all plots are combined on one plot but concatenated.
I hope, you understand me. Many thanks.

Comment: You want all the lines in one plot? Or you want multiple plots side by same in the same figure?

Comment: multiple plots in the same figure, whereby every next plot is concatenated with last plot. On the figure above, the plot ends on 56 and the next plot should start after 56. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I believe so, I just posted a possibly solution based on my understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why are you using so many `eval`s in your code?!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be taught as an example for **How you should never write code in Matlab!**, your massive use of `eval` make it virtually impossible to follow your code. Hence, I'll just drop here what I think may solve your problem, but for any explanations, you would first need to rewrite your code in a proper way (you may want to read [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)).

```
c = 0;
for k=1:(rx * tx)    
    for m=1:(rx * tx)
        eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d_t = corrcoef(m_a%d_abs, m_b%d_abs)', pairs(k), pairs(m), pairs(k), pairs(m)));
        eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d = t_%d_%d_t(1, 2)', pairs(k), pairs(m), pairs(k), pairs(m)));
        if(eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d', pairs(k), pairs(m))) >= max_cor)
            nx = eval(sprintf('numel(a%d)', pairs(k)));
            X = c+1:(c+nx);
            eval(sprintf('plot(X,a%d, ''r'')', pairs(k)));
            hold on;
            eval(sprintf('plot(X,b%d, ''b'')', pairs(m)));
            c = c+nx;
            xlabel('Tones (f)');
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: In a shameless self-plug I'd also suggest looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226214/matlab-loop-through-the-values-of-a-list-from-who-function/40226542#40226542) to see how one can painlessly escape from the dynamic variable name pit of `eval` doom using `save`/`load`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `figure` command out of the loop, only opening one figure for all plots:

```
figure;

for i=1:(rx * tx)    
    for j=1:(rx * tx)
        eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d_t = corrcoef(m_a%d_abs, m_b%d_abs)', pairs(i), pairs(j), pairs(i), pairs(j)));
        eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d = t_%d_%d_t(1, 2)', pairs(i), pairs(j), pairs(i), pairs(j)));

        if(eval(sprintf('t_%d_%d', pairs(i), pairs(j))) >= max_cor)
            eval(sprintf('(''name'', ''a (%d) <> b (%d)'')', pairs(i), pairs(j)));
            eval(sprintf('plot(a%d, ''r'')', pairs(i)));
            hold on;
            eval(sprintf('plot(b%d, ''b'')', pairs(j)));
            xlabel('Tones (f)');
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Ok, but this solutions plots all data on the same range (1-56) and does not concatenate. For example, the for loop plots 5 figures. I want that all tease plots are on the same figure BUT CONCATENATED.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without having access to the values you're plotting, but I think the issue is that you aren't specifying a x-values, in your plot command, so MATLAB is just using the index of each value as the x coordinate. To not use the indices you would have to specify both x and y values in your plot command, for example, plot(57:112, data), etc. As an aside the code could be rewritten to be more readable by eliminating the use of sprintf and eval statements to construct the variables.

Comment: @MarkDelphi Perhaps it would be better to define exactly what you mean by concatenation rather than SHOUTING at people who are trying to help you. It would also have been much better to have added this clarification to your previous question rather than opening a new one.

Comment: I shout nobody. I just define the problem. Also, I am very glad that someone tries to help me.

Comment: @MarkDelphi By typing in ALL CAPS, it appears that you are shouting. Obviously, some people have not understood what you mean by concatenation, so perhaps you could give an example or explain in a different way. Also, using `eval` like that is bad. I know other commenters have said this, but it can't be repeated enough. `eval` is bad bad bad bad bad.

Comment: eval allows accessing to the dynamic variable. SO, I posted a new equation

Comment: eval allows accessing to the dynamic variable. So, I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748386/how-to-concatinete-these-subplots-on-one-graph) which is more simple to understand.